# Dataset (sql query) for each cell (table) in iReport 5.6.0

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to create table in iReport with every cells having different queries (data-sets).

I am able to do by creating different tables with limiting to one cell and merging the multiple tables in Detail band. But looks like its not a optimal solution.

In short, I wanted to fill each cell with different query in a given table. Is that possible?

Following code is written for two data-sets for two different tables:

```
<subDataset name="cell1" uuid="86ffe7f4-2494-40e4-bbc4-4c788e89ac8c">
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id
        FROM patientbill
       where id = 463
    </queryString>
    <field name="id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
</subDataset>
<subDataset name="cell2" uuid="66267ea4-db72-4a56-ae9f-a2d3be11a851">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT billnumber
  FROM patientbill
  where id = 463
    </queryString>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found alternative. Perhaps, its an hack. As, I have mentioned in my question that you cant have sub-dataset to single cell. To accomplish multiple queries in report use different tables with sub-datasets.

Bottom line is that you can't have sub-datsets in Jasper iReport.

-Thank you